# How to set up transparent background in XFCE terminal?

Tags: command-line, 11.10, xubuntu, xfce, transparency

I can't find the option to make the terminal background transparent :-( Any idea where can it be?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to Preferences, Appearance tab, Under Background select 'Transparent Background' and move the slider beneath it to the left.

The option may be hidden if no Compositor is active, either built-in or Compiz.

Answer (score 8):

To enable compositor, please check:

```
Applications > Settings > Settings Manager > Window Manager Tweaks > Compositor > Enable display compositing
```

Answer (score 0):

@kholis is totally right, just take in account that for [terminator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/) you should reinit app.

[image]