# Is there a way to make the terminal show a background with compositing

Tags: xfce, compositing

I like using window compositing because it makes all my windows look good and have shadows, however it makes the terminal show through when I have it on. Is there a way to disable window compositing for the terminal or something similar?

What I want:
[image: What I want]

What I get with compositing on:
[image: What I get with compositing on]

Comment: Have you disabled transparency in XFCE Terminal? http://askubuntu.com/q/63179/158442

Comment: that just makes the terminal look bad

Comment: I didnt get it, do you want to set a background image for Terminal?

Comment: I want to have the desktop background be my terminal background @SadeghGhasemi

Comment: I have Xubuntu 14.04 with the Xfce 4.12 upgrade and I can have transparency enabled with a background image.

Comment: @jbrock does that make it so the terminal window sees through all your other windows to the background? You might just have your compositor off

Comment: @Azdrif Ydkkaba The background image is one that you choose from within Xfce Terminal. It is not the desktop background.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and right click somewhere in the window. From **Profiles** select Profile preference. Then go to **Background** tab and select **Background image** then choose a picture and click open.

[image]

You can also select if you want the picture to scroll or not.

Comment: I think OP is using XFCE4 Terminal and that screenshot is for GNOME Terminal.

Comment: Yeah but they are almost similar. He can notice the differences.

Comment: this won't give the effect where the background stays in the same place as the window moves (at least not in xfce erminal)